# How do I auto-generate IDs for an @ElementCollection when it is a java.util.Map?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I’m using MySQL 5.5.37, JPA 2.0, and Hibernate 4.1.0.Final (I’m willing to upgrade if it solves my problem).  I have the following entity …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "url")
public class Url implements Serializable 
{

    …
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="property_name")
    @Column(name="property_value")
    @CollectionTable(name="url_property", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="url_id"))
    private Map<String,String> properties;
```

The “url_property” table has an ID (primary key) column, and perhaps for this reason, when I create a new Url entity with multiple properties, I feet the exception

```
[ERROR]: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

upon saving.  Does anyone know what I have to do to auto-generate IDs for my url_property table?  I would prefer not to write a trigger, but rather do something JPA, or at least, Hibernate sanctioned.

**Edit:** Per the first suggestion in the answer, I tried

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="property_value")
@CollectionTable(name="url_property", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="url_id"))
private Set<UrlProperty> properties;
```

but it resulted in the exception, "org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK24E4A95BB0648B:url_property [properties_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (url_property [url_id,properties_id])".

My UrlProperty entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "url_property")
public class UrlProperty 
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="URL_ID")
    private SubdomainUrl url;

    @Column(name="PROPERTY_NAME")
    private String propertyName;

    @Column(name="PROPERTY_VALUE")
    private String propertyValue;
```

Comment: The url_property "id" column will be the "id" of the Url class that it relates to (i.e a FK). You don't generate them for the collection table. When using a Map i'd expect the "url_id" and "property_name" to be the composite PK of the "url_property" table.

Comment: Ok, so how do I tell JPA to generate that composite primary key as you suggest?  Right now, it appears the key being generated is just the empty string.

Comment: ought to be automatic, requiring no further config ... or at least it is for my JPA provider (DataNucleus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only told JPA about 3 fields in the table ("property_name","property_value" and "url_id"), so it has no way of knowing about the 4th field used as the pk.  Since it is not an entity, it doesn't have an Identity that is maintained.  Options are:

1) Map the "url_property" table to a Property entity, which would have an ID, value and reference to the Url.  The Url would then have a 1:M reference to the Property class, and can still be keyed on the name.   http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/MapKeyColumns has an example

2) Change your table to remove the ID field, and instead use "property_name","property_value" and "url_id" as the primary key.

3) Set a trigger to populate the ID.  Doesn't seem useful though since the application is never aware of the field anyway.

Comment: For your first suggestion, I tried the above in my question, but it resulted in an "org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK24E4A95BB0648B:url_property [properties_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (url_property [url_id,properties_id])" exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: For #1 I was suggesting using a OneToMany instead of an element collection, as described in the first example in the link provided.  The exception is because you are using an ElementCollection, which implies the object doesn't have its own ID and must use its parent's identity.  Removing the ElementCollection, Column and CollectionTable annotations and replacing them with OneToMany(mappedBy="SubdomainUrl") will resolve the problem